# RPC:S-7:AEC-0 when trying to purchase a product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Currently I'm developing In App purchasing for an application and I'm trying to test it using real purchases and a test account. I can make static purchases already and I can retrieve a list of products. I can also make purchases in the Play Store. However, I keep getting the error when I'm trying to purchase a product in my application:

```
Error while retrieving information from server.[RPC:S-7:AEC-0]
```

If I check logcat it says:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/commitPurchase
```

This is what I already tried:

- Different devices
- Different accounts
- Factory reset
- Clearing Google Play's cache
- Resetting the account
- At first I thought it could by that I'm using carrier billing, but using another account with an actual credit card didn't solve the problem.
- Alpha testing and installing the app from the playstore
- TrivialDrive project gives the same error
- The version on my phone is the same as the version in the developers console

Are there any solutions or requirements to my testing account that I have missed?

P.S. I am using the util classes from the example code.

[edit] I tried to run the TrivialDrive project using my skus, that didn't work either.

[edit] Could it have anything to do with code obfuscation by Proguard?

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this problem in the end? I'm getting the exact some error as you.

Comment: Unfortunately not, since I don't work on this project anymore.